# GAMS decimal numbers

Tags: random, long-integer, gams-math

I have the following code:

```
loop (d,
 rnd(d)=uniformInt(1,nd)
 );
```

I am going to use the integer numbers `rnd(d)` as an index of another set `s(i)`. But for example when `rnd(d)=34.000`  however, it is integer, but `s(34.000)` has no valid index since, `34.000` is not `34` !! and GAMS shows a error message.

Comment: Can you show your code, where you try to use rnd, that produces the error?

Comment: my code is above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if @Lutz solution worked out for you. In case it did not, you can try the following:
First, it is not necessary to loop over the set d, just a simple:

```
rnd(d) = uniformInt(1,nd);
```

will suffice.
Next line can go like:

```
loop(d,
     s(i)$(i.val = ord(d)) = . . .;
     );
```

If you still have issues, then using @Lutz suggestion just append '*1.000' to 'ord(i)' and/or 'rnd(d)', whichever is giving you issues.

Answer (score 0):

Is i an ordered set? If yes, you could use something like this:

```
loop(d,
  s(i)$(ord(i)=rnd(d)) = ...;
)
```